# Let $I$ be an ideal in $C$, if $ f \equiv r $(mod $I$), then $ r \in f[X]$

Tags: general-topology, ideals

The set $  C= C ( X ) $ of all continuous, real valued functions on a topological space$ X$  will be provided with an algebraic structure and an order structure.

$C^* (X) = \{ f \in C(X) \vert \quad  f\quad  is \quad bounded \}$.

Subset $ I \subseteq C (X)$ is an ideal when  $I$ is subring of $C(X)$ and $\forall f \in I , g \in C(X), \quad f.g \in I $

**Are the following statements  correct?**

> 1: Let $I$ be an ideal in $C$, if $ f \equiv r $(mod $I$), then $ r
>  \in f[X]$.

2:Let $I$ be an ideal in $C^{*}$, if $ f \equiv r $(mod $I$), then $ r
 \in \overline{f[X]}_{\mathbb{R}}$.

**$f[ X] = \{ fx \vert x \in X \}$**

Comment: This doesn't make much sense,  for  at least  two reasons: First, there's that  $I$  in the hypothesis but not in the conclusion. Second, if I understand the notation  in the definition of $f[X]$, then $f[X]\subset\mathbb R$, so it can't possibly contain $r$, since $r$ is not a real number.

Answer (score 0):

For $r \in \mathbb{R}$ we denote by $\mathbf{r}$ the function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with value $r$, so $\forall x \in X: \mathbf{r}(x)= r$.

Note that for the result to hold, $I$ should be a *proper* ideal (this is often implicit in the definition of ideal in many texts), i.e. $I \neq C(X)$ (or $C^\ast(X)$ resp.). This is equivalent to $I$ does not contain a unit of the ring. (if $u \in I$ is a unit with inverse $u'$ in the ideal $I$ then for any ring element $x$, $x = u(u'x) \in I$, as $u\in I$).

So then assume $f \equiv \mathbf{r} \bmod{I}$. This means by definition that $g:= f - \mathbf{r} \in I$. So **if** $r \notin f[X]$, $f(x) \neq r$ for all $x \in X$, so $g(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in X$. But then $g \in I$ is a unit in $C(X)$, as $\frac{1}{g(x)}$ is a well-defined continuous function on $X$.  This contradiction shows that $r \in f[X]$.

The bounded function ring case is slightly more subtle:
If $f \equiv \mathbf{r} \bmod{I}$ in $C^\ast(X)$, so again $g= f - \mathbf{r}\in I$ then *suppose* $r \notin \overline{f[X]}$. So for some $\delta >0$ we have that $B(r,\delta) \cap f[X] = \emptyset$. This implies that $|g(x)| \ge \delta >0$, so now $\frac{1}{g}$ is not only well-defined and continuous, but bounded as well (by $\frac{1}{\delta}$), making $g \in I$ a unit in $C^\ast(X)$, contradiction again, so $r \in \overline{f[X]}$.